# PM2: How to reset useless ids of pm2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, devops, pm2

Here is the situation :).

For instance, we have 2 ran instances using PM2. They have appropriate ids, `#0`, `#1`.
And we have added other instances(`#2`, `#3`, `#4`), which were removed after some time.
So, when we run a new instance, we will receive the id as `#5`. But we have only two ran instances, so it will be logical to have a new id that will increment a last ran instance's id.

The meaning of the question is how we can reset or clean the unused ids from the PM2, without killing the current PM2 process.

I know about the command

```
 pm2 kill
```

But in this case, we are killing the current pm2 process, which means that we will kill all our ran instances.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify the purpose of doing this？Maybe we can find some alternative way.

Comment: The goal is that I want to clear all useless ids. For instance, I have two ran instances(#0, #1), and after I have run 3 new instances(#2, #3, #4). After I have removed #2 and #3 instances. And have run a new instance. I want to see #3 for the new instance, instead of #5. It's logical since I have only 3 ran instances. So I want to understand is it possible to do without killing the PM2 process.

Comment: PM2 has never provided a way to allow you to customize the id of process. If you feel inconvenient about how PM2 assigns id, you may get all processes' info by PM2’s NodeJS API, and then apply your own logic on it. Checkout the doc: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/

Comment: Yup. I know about the API @辛忠柱. Thanks.  Looks like it is not possible.

Comment: As a relatively new user of PM2, I Googled a solution to this exact same question which is what brought me here.  It's a minor irritation that process ids aren

Comment: I understand you perfectly @ChefTech :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much researches, I don't found any solution to solve the goal of the question.
Looks like the only way to reset ids of PM2, its kill command

```
pm2 kill
```

> **IMPORTANT: When using this command all ran instances will be deleted, and ids will be reset**.

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 update
```

but keep in mind this will restart all processes and rename all ids to fill the gaps

For instance, I have two ran instances (#0, #1), and after I have run 3 new instances (#2, #3, #4). After I have removed #2 and #3 instances.

`pm2 update` will rename all back from `0` to `2`, order might also be different

also note: please do `pm2 save` before attempting this